# Error in installation of Pandas on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, ubuntu, data-science

I am installing cdqa through the command "pip3 install cdqa", in pycharm virtual environment, but during installation I get this error:

command x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc failed with exit status 1
ERROR: Failed building wheel for pandas

I tried installing pandas separately and it successfully installs
Installing collected packages: pandas
Successfully installed pandas-1.1.5

When i again install cdqa, it stucks on
"Building wheels for collected packages: pandas
Building wheel for pandas (setup.py)"
and gives the same error.

Tried on Jupiter Notebook and Pycharm both.

I am on Ubuntu 18.04 desktop version.
Python 3.8.6

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [cdqa repo](https://github.com/cdqa-suite/cdQA) says

> ⛔ [NOT MAINTAINED] This repository is no longer maintained, but is being kept around for educational purposes. If you want a maintained alternative to cdQA check out: https://github.com/deepset-ai/haystack

so you should probably switch to that.

As for why you're getting this issue, [cdqa is locked to pandas==0.25.0](https://github.com/cdqa-suite/cdQA/blob/40387925db8f0da44a5bd2fe549cde675a92d479/requirements.txt#L4), which is positively ancient, and as such there is no Python 3.8 Linux binary wheel, which means Python is attempting to build it from source. That generally fails unless you've got all the development packages you need. When you just `pip install pandas`, you're getting a newer version from a binary wheel you don't need to compile.

Comment: Right. Thanks. I tried in Google Colab, and it worked. Why is that? Just trying to understand the environments.

Comment: Colab might use an older Python for which there is a wheel, or they may have the dependencies required to build Pandas from source.